# How to select a workbook that has a random name, when you have 2 open workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-2010

So, essentially I export a data set from a website and the data set comes in an excel file. The file is always named as such "Task_State_(Pivot)_xxxxxx" X's are a random string of numbers. The work I do involves me having 2 excel files open, including the downloaded file and taking the downloaded one (task_State_(Pivot)) and taking that data and copying it in my other excel file, which acts as my masterfile of sorts. My question is, how do I select that workbook if I don't know the full name of it because of the random string of numbers at the end? I can't really activate the workbook because I don't have the full name since it always changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Loop through all open workbooks and do something along the lines of `If InStr(wkbkname, "Task_State_(Pivot)_") Then` and set that to the workbook - or you could use `Like` - a couple of options here.

Comment: What do you mean by download?  Is the workbook for the downloaded file opened automatically once it has been downloaded?  If the downloaded file results in an open workbook it is likely the active workbook.

Comment: It is, however, I want to make it so if my other file is activated, to activate the downloaded one instead.

Comment: Use  workbooks(2)

Comment: 'It is, however, I want to make it so if my other file is activated, to activate the downloaded one instead.'

Then you need to show the code that causes the file to be downloaded. When we see this code it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Freeflow There's no code that causes the file to be downloaded. Just go to my company's website and download the file.I do this part manually for now.

Comment: Then you download it to a specified empty folder. As it's the only file in the folder it's easy to find and open and hence get the namr. When your code is done with the download it either deletes the file or renamed it and moves it to a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
  If wb.Name <> "your_file_name" Then

        'do whatever you want ot do with your other wb

  End If
Next wb
```

Comment: will this work even if I put in my file name but not the full name, only the portion that I know of without the ending of random digits?

Comment: It's up to you how you want to implement it.  You cam make it instead into something like `If Left(wb.Name,10) = "Task_State" Then`.. etc

Comment: Right, I got that far. However, my main problem with this whole thing is how exactly do I go and format it so that I select the unknown workbook? What would be placed after my then... ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is a good start, but I'd add stuff to allow the user to confirm the correct sheet name once at the start:

Note: you may have other spreadsheets open or if you are using macros, you may also have a personal macro workbook open (in the background) - you don't want to write to that.

1. create a global variable to hold the name of the workbook that you are working on today, and the first time code tries to open it, get the user to confirm the name:
   eg: Dim strGlobalNewWorkbook As String
2. inside the loop (and the if) that Michal Rosa suggests, put code that does this:

   ```
       If MsgBox("please confirm that you want to process workbook: " & wb.Name, vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
       strGlobalNewWorkbook = wb.Name
       Exit Sub
   End If
   ```
3. then you can access the correct workbook from code using the format:
    Application.Workbooks(strGlobalNewWorkbook).Name ' eg: get the name back